# WordPress carousel plugin

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

Does anybody know of any tutorials or even better a pre-built WordPress plugin that is a carousel that looks like the below:

[image]

Basically I want a carousel that displays image and text(that are links). I need a carousel that is responsive.

Comment: http://amazingcarousel.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jetpack plugin is a powerful plugin with a lot features and one of them is that convert all your normal galleries into a carousel galleries. You can try it!

You can download it from here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/

Comment: Thank you, that's what I am after :-)